# Nested Iframe - a quick way to get into it - does it exist?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, nested

```
Site HTML
<iframe1>
     <html>
      <head>
      <body>
       <iframe2>
        <html>
         <head>
         <body>
          <iframe3>
            <html>
             <head>
             <body>
           <div>
            <iframe4A>
           </div>
           <div>
            <iframe4B>
           </div>
        </body>
    .....
```

I am taking my first steps in writing tests in Python Selenium.
I have such a structure in html.
I need to get to "Frame4A" first, get something from it, then to "Frame4B" an also get it something frome them, and later back to the normal page.
To put it exactly, "Frame1" is such a prompt that pops up on the page (takes up its entire surface)
I have to do something in him to get rid of him

All frames have an ID or class, so no problem.

**My questions is:**

- Should you really do it in exactly this order?
  There is no way to jump from dra to "Frame4" ??
- And will the command from the eighth point after closing all this popup "Frame1" return me to the original first html page?

wait...

1. ...until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.locator,"Frame1")))
2. ...until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.locator,"Frame2")))
3. ...until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.locator,"Frame3")))
4. ...until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.locator,"Frame4A")))
5. get something
6. ...until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.locator,"Frame4B")))
7. get something
8. driver.switch_to.default_content()

Comment: It's nested so yes you have to go 1 by 1.

Comment: And if I'm already in "Frame4B" and want to go back to "Frame 3"

Then I have to go back to "HTML" and all over again "frame1 / frame2 / frame3"

?